# Tweak command-line position and size

Tags: command-line

The command-line is obviously a very convenient tool in vim.

However, especially when working with splits, it can feel uncomfortable to have to look back and forth between window and command-line (e.g: typing a regex to find something in the top-right window).

Ideally, I would like to have one command-line per window to keep it close to the text I'm currently editing.

Is there any way to achieve something similar?

Comment: Hm, I had thought recently about trying to implement a popup that acted as the command line; I never worked through in my head how it would work with completion and maps and all though.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do the exact same. after some searching I found this plugin: https://github.com/folke/noice.nvim (only works for neovim though)

Comment: That looks promising!